# How do I know when a valgrind error is caused by my code or by some library my code is depending on?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am new to valgrind and have a conceptual question about how to read the stack trace of a valgrind error.

In particular, I'm running an example opengl application which doesn't do all that much, just opens a window and displays a triangle. The code is from some github opengl example repository, so of course, no guarantees that this code is without problems.

Anyway, when I run `valgrind -v executable` on it I get lots of error reports like this one here.

```
==26727== 522 errors in context 590 of 590:
==26727== Invalid write of size 2
==26727==    at 0x4C36753: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26727==    by 0xEC9A77C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==26727==    by 0xECAD278: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==26727==    by 0xEDBCD50: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==26727==    by 0xEDC7E1B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so)
==26727==    by 0x10E929: vinz::Scene::run() (scene.cpp:139)
==26727==    by 0x10DFE6: main (main.cpp:42)
==26727==  Address 0x7fa12047d300 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Does this mean the problem is caused by my code (so, something bad happens at scene.cpp:139), or does it mean that somewhere deep down in the dependencies there is an invalid write, and therefore I'm off the hook, so to speak?

Can I assume that, if the first line in the error stack is referring to my code, that I am the culprit, but if the first line in the valgrind error stack is from some dependency, that then I am not the one causing it?

In particular I've read in the valgrind manual in the section on Suppressing errors:

> The error-checking tools detect numerous problems in the system libraries, such as the C library, which come pre-installed with your OS. You can't easily fix these, but you don't want to see these errors (and yes, there are many!)

Comment: There's no simple answer, unfortunately. Sometimes errors reported from deep inside an opaque call stack are indeed errors in that library, which you can't do anything about, but sometimes it can also be caused by incorrect arguments that you pass to a top-level function.

Comment: Ok.. so I guess in those cases where it's unclear one will have to find other means of discerning the cause? Are there other tools for this?